# Nodejs v7x crypto module returns bad decrypt

Tags: node.js, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt, decrypt a simple text with `Nodejs` v7 using its `crypto` module.

The algorithm I chose is `aes 256 cbc`

From the documentation, I understand that

1. It is better to use `crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv)` than `crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password)` (the same for decipher object)
2. The `iv` (or `salt`) can be generated by `mySalt = crypto.randomBytes(16)`
3. Then, the key can be generated by `var myKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('secret', mySalt, 100000, 32, 'md5')`

My full code snippet is as follows:

```
//generate salt (iv) and key
var mySalt = crypto.randomBytes(16)
var myKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync('secret', mySalt, 100000, 32, 'md5');

//create cypher object and encrypt a text
var myCipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc',myKey,mySalt)
let myEncrypted = myCipher.update('some clear text data', 'utf8', 'hex');
myEncrypted += myCipher.final('hex')

//create decipher object and decrypt a myEncrypted
var myDecipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-cbc',myKey,mySalt)
var myDecrypted = myDecipher.update(myEncrypted, 'hex', 'utf8');
myDecrypted += myDecipher.final('utf8')
```

Encrypting phase works as expected, no errors were thrown. However, an error was thrown in decrypting phase (at the very last line):

> Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
>       at Decipher.final (internal/crypto/cipher.js:164:28)

I have done a lot of researches on this already, including similar questions on SO. Also, trying `decrypt.setAutoPadding(false)` doesn't work.

Comment: `crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc',myKey,mySalt)`. You forget the `iv`.

Comment: the `crypto.createDecipheriv` method only accepts 3 parameters. In my code, `mySalt` is the `iv`

Comment: [See](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options), and you already 3 parameters.

Comment: I followed the link and see the signature `crypto.createDecipheriv(algorithm, key, iv[, options])`. So when I call it with `crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc',myKey,mySalt)`, `mySalt` is used as the `iv`. Would you mind telling me what you think is the problem with my code again?

Comment: Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: yes, I do. The problem persists.

Comment: It seems you have a typo, it's `createDecipheriv`, not `createDecipher`. `createDecipher` doesn't accept an IV, your IV is passed in the `options` parameter and so it is not used.